# Convergence of $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sin^2(\frac{1}{i})$ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\cos^2(\frac{1}{i}).$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to check convergence of these sums: $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \sin^2\left(\frac{1}{i}\right)\qquad\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\cos^2\left(\frac{1}{i}\right).$$ Does comparing these sums to $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2}$ have any logic? Thanks for help.

Comment: Why is it that your index $i$ doesn't show up in any of the summands?

Comment: Try to use the fact that $|\sin x| \leq x$ and for $\cos$ something analogously.

Comment: @Fabian Or not.

Comment: I belive that the op meant $\frac{1}{i}$

Comment: It is quite obvious (but I guess Did has some fun)...

Comment: @Fabian Why did you modify the question? To make your comment apply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the problem has been edited a bit.  The first series;
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \sin^2\left(\frac{1}{i}\right)\qquad  $$ 
This converges, and is comparable to $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2}$ because $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$

The second series:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\cos^2\left(\frac{1}{i}\right).$$
This diverges because the terms converge to 1.

Answer (score 2):

We can see
$$
\left\lvert \, \sin \left( \frac{1}{i} \right) \, \right\rvert \le \frac{1}{i} \implies \sqrt{\sin^2 (1/i)} \le 1/i \implies \sin^2 (1/i) \le \frac{1}{i^2}
$$
so we can deduce the $\sin^2 (1/i)$ series converges since $1/i^2$ converges. For $\cos^2 1/i$ we can see
$$
\cos^2 (1/i) \to 1
$$
so the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

The only case when a series $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a(x)$ converges, where $a(x)$ does not depend on $i$, is when $a(x)=0$. For example, the first series converges if and only if $x=1/(n\pi)$ for some nonzero integer $n$.

Comment: @downvoter Have a look at the history of the question and you are in for a surprise (that is, if your concern is genuine).

Comment: This answer is actually very amusing(even coming from someone who makes similar errors to the OP).